# Tooltip with user defined function

Tags: tooltip

How can I evaluate in a pointlist

```
ListPlot[Tooltip[RandomReal[{0,1},{5,2}]]]
```

for example the product of the point coordinate  values?

I tried `ListPlot[Tooltip[RandomReal[{0,1},{5,2}],#1 #2 &]]`
but didn't succeed.

Thanks!

Comment: `ListPlot[Tooltip[#, Times @@ #] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 2}]]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick anser!